# Return data from database in servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I have read a lot of info on ServiceStack and love the simplicity. Using a fixed class which gets compiled into the program is easy but I have a more flexible need.

A simple webservice in which you can ask a question to a database.

```
<NAV>
<message>GET 300</message>
</NAV>
```

The database responds with an xml:

```
<NAV>
<Contacts>

<Contact>
<No>123</No>
<Name>jan</Name>
</Contact>

<Contact>
<No>334</No>
<Name>John</Name>
</Contact>

</Contacts>
</NAV>
```

Can this be returned by servicestack as Json?

Note: Depending on the question the database can return:

```
<Contacts> 
<Customers>
etc.
```

depending on the question.

Comment: The question is a little confusing. How are you requesting the resource? Using ServiceStack you can get json simply by adding "?format=json" to the requesting url.

Comment: What does the implementation of your service look like? are you returning an object or XML? If you're returning XML string, it can't be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database responds with XML than no further transformations can be applied and the response will be the XML Literal un-touched.

In order to support the other ServiceStack built-in formats you need to deserialize the XML into C# POCOs and return that.

Comment: so I need to create the class first, and then deserialize the xml to the class.
The problem with this is that I don't know what the database returns after compilation of the program.

Comment: No, if you want to support other formats it needs to be returned unserialized in clean C# POCOs/DTOs.